# Como fazer um merge nas duas aplicações que estão em um GitLab separadas?

Tags: git, gitlab

Peguei um trabalho onde o pessoal tem duas versões.

Vou explicar melhor:

1. Uma empresa A transferiu um cliente para outra empresa B, ambas de TI.
2. A Empresa A passou uma versão e os backlogs para a empresa B.
3. A empresa A fez novas implementações e a Empresa B também.

Preciso fazer um merge nas duas aplicações que estão em um GitLab separadas: da empresa A e B, ambos com suas modificações. E fazer versão "final" para realmente a empresa B ter versão atualizada de ambas.

Qual o melhor caminho para fazer isso? Estou meio perdido neste processo. Queria executar da melhor forma, sem testes por ser a primeira vez que faço isso.

Comment: Bem, um havia os commit realizados e outro veio para a empresa e o desenvolvedor anterior não fez nenhum commit na versão dele, então me enganei em relação ao uso de Git. Mas a ideia seria esta mesma postada pelo @Fernando Silveira. O que utilizei aqui foi o Meld ([https://meldmerge.org/](https://meldmerge.org/)). Deu trabalho, mas como é modularizado e por componentes foi correto. Obrigado pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem tudo o que você quer fazer é um merge entre dois branches diferentes de dois repositórios diferentes. Para este caso vamos chamar os branches de "branch-a" e "branch-b", e os repositórios de "repo-a" e "repo-b".

1. Primeiramente crie um repositório local e baixe os repositórios das empresas A e B:

```
$ git init repo
$ cd repo
$ git remote add repo-a https://gitlab.com/empresa-a/app
$ git remote add repo-b https://gitlab.com/empresa-b/app
$ git fetch repo-a
$ git fetch repo-b
```

2. Os dois repositórios e branches foram baixados e agora você precisa criar um branch local a partir de um dos dois. No caso escolhi o "branch-a":

```
$ git checkout -b branch-local repo-a/branch-a
```

3. Depois basta fazer o merge do branch "branch-b" para o local:

```
$ git merge repo-b/branch-b
```

4. Caso haja conflitos, resolva-os e faça o(s) commit(s);
5. Faça o push para o seu repositório:

```
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/sua-empresa/app
$ git push -u origin branch-local
```

Apesar de neste exemplo eu ter considerado a possibilidade do nome dos branches serem diferentes, pode ser que no seu caso os branches tenham o mesmo nome (master?) e mesmo assim as instruções acima funcionaria.